# Split by square bracket, even though there is no text inside bracket

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem to split the text by using square bracket into array. If there is no text inside square bracket, then it won't be catch. The code is in JavaScript like the example below:

```
var text = 'This note is created on [date] by [admin;operator] for []'
var myArray = text.match(/\[([^[]+)\]/g);
console.log(myArray);
```

and the result is

```
["[date]", "[admin;operator]"]
```

but what I want is

```
["[date]", "[admin;operator]", []]
```

How to improve my pattern to get the blank square bracket ([])?

Comment: Welcome to SO.. please finish the tour. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: @ZF007 thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `+` (1 or more) with `*` (0 or more)

```js
var text = 'This note is created on [date] by [admin;operator] for []'
var myArray = text.match(/\[([^[]*)\]/g);
console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

`n+`    Matches any string that contains at least one n

`n*`  Matches any string that contains zero or more occurrences of n

```js
var text = 'This note is created on [date] by [admin;operator] for []'
var myArray = text.match(/\[([^[]*)\]/g);
console.log(myArray);
```